# Service worker: caching cross-domain response with all static assets as well

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am currently working on a proof-of-concept for a project but I just can't get my head around

1. documentation
2. and implementation :)

The case is as follows:

I have my main app (React) that has a list of links. All of them link to a specific page.
These links open up in an iframe.
That's all basically.

So my app runs on "app.domain.com" and the forms urls are like "pages.domain.com/pages/pageA.html" etc.
What I need to do in this poc is to make these pages offline available, including(!) the assets for this pages (css/js/img)

I already created a simple service worker.

```
const CACHE_NAME = "poc-forms";

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  console.log("sw installing…");
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  console.log("sw now ready to handle fetches");
  event.waitUntil(caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(() => self.clients.claim()));
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url);

  if (url.pathname.includes("forms")) {
    event.respondWith(
      (async function () {
        var cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        var cachedFiles = await cache.match(event.request);
        if (cachedFiles) {
          return cachedFiles;
        } else {
          try {
            var response = await fetch(event.request);
            await cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
            return response;
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(" something when wrong!");
          }
        }
      })()
    );
  }
});
```

It fetches the request and checks if it's already in the cache or not.
If it's not, cache it.
This works.

But where I'm stuck:

1. how can I also store the css and js that are needed for the pages as well? Do I need find a way to get all links and loop over them, fetch them and store them?
2. I heard about Google Workbox, also went through the documentation but it's just not clear to me, like how to transform my current SW into something that works with workbox, with the whole registerRoute-thing on a fetch...
3. the service worker will only capture the fetches when the page is refreshed. The clients.claim() should fix this, but it doesn't actually...

If someone out there could help me out with this, much appreciated!

thanks,

Mario

Answer (score 0):

The Service Worker APIs do not allow for a service worker registered on `app.domain.com` to control either navigation requests or subresource requests associated with an `<iframe>` that is hosted on `pages.domain.com`. That's not something that Workbox can help with—it's just not possible.

From the perspective of the service worker, an `<iframe>` with a different origin than the host page is equivalent to a new window or tab with a different origin. The service worker can't "see" or take control of it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we ended up using a different approach, because the app we are loading inside the iframe exposed an api apparently, where we can hook into.

To cache the entire page, with all the assets, this was the code that worked for me:

```
importScripts(
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.2/workbox-sw.js"
);

const { skipWaiting, clientsClaim } = workbox.core;
const { registerRoute } = workbox.routing;
const { StaleWhileRevalidate } = workbox.strategies;

skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();


registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => {
    console.log(" request ", request.destination);
    return (
request.destination === "iframe" ||
      request.destination === "document" ||
      request.destination === "image" ||
      request.destination === "script" ||
      request.destination === "style" ||
      request.destination === "font"
    );
  },
  new StaleWhileRevalidate()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, this might help others, small variant of what I want to accomplish:

[Why isn't my offline cached subdomain page not loading when called from other subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63302801/why-isnt-my-offline-cached-subdomain-page-not-loading-when-called-from-other-su/63329109#63329109)